# Simple Ajax Call to MVC method always returns error

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller

I have a very simple ajax call to an MVC method and it always return an error with a blank responseText.  I have called and used ajax for many years and cannot seem to figure what is causing this:

here is the js code:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "/Mobile/MyMVCMethod",
    data: null,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (data) {
        alert("test");
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(status);
        alert(request.responseText);
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

here is my C#:

```
[HttpPost]
public string MyMVCMethod()
{
    return "test";
}
```

the code makes it to method but return an error with no details

I have tried ActionResult because I wanted to return a PartialView but since it was not working I tried to narrow it down and find out if will work with just a string.  THis is happening even if the C# was this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyMVCMethod()
{
    return PartialView("MyView");
}
```

MyView:

```
<div>hello world</div>
```

Now I see an error in Ajax " Resource Not Found"  even though it executed the MVC method

Comment: There is no `dataType: 'text'`, possible options are `xml, json, script, or html`. Or just delete it all together, and jqeury will try to figure it out for you

Comment: still the same issue with dataType: 'html'.

Comment: Have you add [HttpPost] attribute to the method?

Comment: added HttpPost yes. now it gives me resource not found.

Comment: You can test by return a string first instead of a PartialView.

Comment: What is the name of the controller and how do you know the MVC method was executed?

Comment: the MVC method was executed. I have a break point there and it hits it just fine.  I have made many many ajax calls. this one just puzzles me..

Comment: @Daniel yes I have tried but returning a STRING and a PARTIALVIEW and a JsonResult all return errors even if the MVC method was executed

Comment: When you say you are getting an error are you getting the 3 alerts in the ajax error function?  Can you post the 3 alert messages?

Comment: its a 404 error " Resource Not Found"

Comment: Somethings not adding up.  You can't get a 404 and have it hit a breakpoint in that action while debugging.  What is the name of the controller that this action is in?  We should also move this to chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c

Comment: Another try, turn to [HttpGet] and type: "GET" in ajax to check.

Comment: Something is wrong. I ran your code in my project and alert("test") triggers

Comment: I don't know what happened.. But I think something was cached. I HIT CTRL + F5 and it works now! thanks everyone for trying

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
        url:"Mobile/MyMethod",
        method:"post", 
         datatype:"json"
}).done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data " + data );
  });
```

and make sure call only normal method not action result.then try it may it will work for you